# Sql запрос как его переделать на LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Не силен в линке у меня есть запрос, который выбирает из трех таблиц контакты.

Выглядит он так

```sql
SELECT * FROM persons p 
LEFT JOIN phones ph ON p.id = ph.person_id 
LEFT JOIN emails e ON p.id = e.person_id
```

Хочу его переписать на Linq  и у меня не получается. Может кто-нибудь помочь?

Comment: какой именно Linq? EF или Linq 2 SQL?

Comment: И добавьте модель данных. Т.к. логично предположить, что у сущности Person есть свойства Emails и Phones. В этом случае и Linq не нужен.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

предположим модели данных выглядят так:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set}
}

public class Phone
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string Phone1 {get;set;}
    public string Phone2 {get;set;}
}

public class Email
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string Email1 {get;set;}
}
```

тогда запрос мог бы выглядеть как то так

```
var person =
    from p in persons
    join ph in phones on ph.PersonId equals p.Id into phonesPerson
    from personWithPhone in phonesPerson.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join e in emails on e.PersonId equals p.Id into emailsPerson
    from personWithEmail in emailsPerson.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
        {
            PersonId = p.Id,
            Phone1 = personWithPhone == null ? string.Empty: personWithPhone.Phone1,
            Phone2 = personWithPhone == null ? string.Empty: personWithPhone.Phone2,
            Email = personWithEmail == null ? string.Empty: personWithEmail.Email1
        }
```

если же используется EF и присутствуют навигационные поля то тогда можно было бы воспользоваться ими для получения необходимой дополнительной информации

Comment: Вам еще нужно добавить проверку на то, что `personWithPhone` и `personWithEmail` не `null`, иначе Ваш код может выдавать `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @ApInvent добавил проверку. в C#6 это выглядело бы менее громоздко

Answer (score 3):

Допустим переменная с контекстом EF называется db. Тогда

```
from p in db.person
join ph in db.phones on p.id equals ph.person_id into ljoin1
            from phone in ljoin1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join e in db.emails on p.id equals e.person_id into ljoin2
            from mail in ljoin2.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
    person = p,
    mail = mail,
    phone = phone
}
```

Соответственно в селекте можете варьировать получаемые значения. Например

```
select new 
{
    person_id = p.id,
    person_name = p.name,
    mail = mail?.details,
    phone_code = phone?.code
}
```

Comment: mail?.details, если я не ошибаюсь это C# 6

Comment: @Bald56rus да, Вы правы. очень приятная фича кстати.

Comment: укажите в своем ответе этот небольшой ньюанс, а то мало ли. я например до сих пор на C#5

Comment: @Bald56rus это LINQ, он скорее всего и `phone_code = phone.code` нормально обработает при `phone == null`. Ведь это не обращение к свойству напрямую, а просто инструкция - взять значение из соответствующей колонки.

Comment: @PashaPash `phone_code = phone.code` вызовет исключение. т.к. `DefaultIfEmpty()` вернет null

Comment: @nikita не обязательно. вызова phone.code реально не происходит

Comment: А как мне вывести все в обычную таблицу? То есть отобразить поля

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Phone> Phones {get;set};
    public IEnumerable<Email> Emails {get;set};
}

public class Phone
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Person Person {get;set;}
}

public class Email
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Person Person {get;set;}
}
```

и можно просто обращаться из кода к телефонам и емейлам как

```
var person = context.Persons.Single(....);

int emailsCount = person.Emails.Count();
Phone firstPhone = person.Phones.First();
```

Comment: Вы доверяете создание связей EF (public IEnumerable<Phone> Phones {get;set;})?! я правильно понял?

Comment: @Bald56rus да, но я код наугад писал. мог что-то пропустить.

Comment: при такой реализации моделей можно было бы использовать automapper, правда пришлось бы создавать еще один класс

Comment: @Bald56rus еще есть вариант без LazyLoad, с Include. На самом деле у топикастера скорее всего Database First, и есть навигационные поля с lazy load.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если просто переписать, то так:

```
var linq = from p in persons
           join ph in phones on p.id equals ph.person_id
           join e in emails on p.id equals e.person_id
           select new { Person = p, Phones = ph, Email = e };
```

Только с выбираемыми полями определитесь, без использования *

Comment: необходимо было вроде левое соединение

Comment: @Bald56rus соединятся непонятно куда, поэтому я привел просто обобщенный вид, как бы запрос мог выглядеть. Дальше дело техники, но в общем Вы  тут и без меня уже все расписали)

Comment: @Bald56rus спасибо, затупил... только сейчас понял о чем вы)